# Tell difference between iOS and Android in a Pure AS3 mobile project in flex 4.5?

Tags: ios, actionscript-3, apache-flex, mobile, flex4.5

Any way to know in the code which platform you are on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Capabilities.os. Returns a string that identifies the host OS.

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/beta/reference/actionscript/3/flash/system/Capabilities.html#os

Comment: And yes it works for iOS. The beta docs don't show a string for Android but I'm sure there is one, it just hasn't been updated. You could do a quick test on your Android device (mine's dead right now or I would) and then you can know what value to expect for android.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post but the answer was never posted.  My Droid Bionic returns Linux with the Kernel Version as the OS of your phone. Just in case someone stumbles across the post.

Returned:
Linux 2.6.35.7-XXXXXX